# Code design with Java Generics

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, type-parameter

Consider the following code:

```
interface A<T> {
  boolean someMethod(T obj);
  boolean someMethod2(String str);
}

class B<T> {
   T obj;
}

class C<T> {
  B<T>[] bObjs;

  public someMethod(A<T> aParam, String str) { 
    //do some stuff
    if(bObjs!=null && aParam!=null) {  
       for(B<T> bObj: bObjs) {
         if(aParam.someMethod(bObj.obj) {
           //doSmth
         }
       }  
      //do smth
    }
    //do smth
  }
```

Problem: use of bObjs and aParam is optional, but it force users of class C to use the type parameter, even when not needed. Is there a way of designing the problem so that this is unnecessary? If I use a wildcard generic such as `B<?>[] bObjs and` `A<?> aParam`then I can't use the method `aParam.someMethod(bObj.obj)`. Is there any way of type checking/type casting to allow use of this method without requiring type parameters? The actual code is obviously more complex, and involves a lot of logic where aParam is used if present - the use of bObjs is pretty much limited to use of a single method involving aParam.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What are the bounds on the type parameter `T`? What does `someMethod` need to be able to do with it? And what are the consequences if you call `someMethod` with a value that is not actually a `T`? Is it acceptable for each `A` implementation to know its own type, so that it could have a method like `Class<T> itemType();` that implementers would need to provide?

Comment: There is no bound for T - a class implementing A might use it for anything where it make sense. someMethod can do anything with it - but it must return true or false. I can do a type check for T - so if some method is called with a type that's not T it won't be the worst thing. It is acceptable for each A implementation to know its own type. Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: If it helps, in the actual code, class A is SemanticContext<T> and someMethod is isConsistentWith(T obj). The implementation might vary widely - e.g  if T is geographic locations, a class implementing SemanticContext might include a country, and any location not contained in the country would be said to be inconsistent with the context. If T is disease, the context might include a required symptom - a disease not having the symptom would be inconsistent. Thanks!

Comment: How is it possible for a semantic context to apply to any type? What would `SemanticContext<Thread>` mean, or `SemanticContext<InputStream>`? Even if you don't have a language-level constraint on `T`, there is obviously a *semantic* constraint on `T`. The question is: what does it mean for `C` to operate in a specific semantic context without knowing anything about the constraint on `T`? As currently described, it sounds entirely appropriate for users of class `C` to have to know about `T` -- I'm trying to understand why it would be safe and correct for them *not* to.

Comment: You are correct - there is a semantic constraint. I'm not sure how to model it and it's not a priority at the moment but I will be happy to look into any suggestions you may have. I included another method in A: someMethod2(String str). This method is widely used in C, which is a spellcorrector and returns spelling suggestions as long as they don't violate any semantic contraints. I essentially want C to be able to run even without any constraints and I am open to any design solutions for this problem. Please let me know if there is any further clarifications that might help. Thank you!